# Excel method to find the values closest to a given period

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, search, logging, worksheet-function

I have some data measured at non uniform time intervals, for example:

```
Time(s)     Value(KB)
  2.1         304
 43.0         400
 60.2         380
 87.0         440
 89.5         445
102.2         460
124.3         470
```

I have this in a CSV with the time increasing from T=0 as above, and I want to sample `Value` at a periodic interval (60 seconds) to match some other data that I have.

I was trying to use Microsoft Excel 2007 to accomplish the task of reducing the data to just the values that are closest to each 60 second interval (there is a bit of data so whether it is always higher (`124.3`), or lower (`102.2`), or absolute value closest (`124.3`), is not important). I have tried applying a formula to the Time column (MOD(Tn, 60)) but I cannot hit on a way to take this output (Time values cycling between 0 and 60) and filter out everything but the closest value to 60 in each cycle. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do the following in another table:

1. Column D: put the values has 60, 120, 180, etc.
2. Column E: `=MATCH(D1,$A:$A)` - this will give you the last row of the where the value is smaller than column D
3. Column F: `=INDEX($A:$A,E1)` - this returns the seconds value that's lower
4. Column G: `=INDEX($A:$A,E1+1)` - this returns the seconds value that's higher
5. Column H: `=INDEX($B:$B,IF(D1-F1&lt;G1-D1,E1+1,E1))` - this will provide you with the value (KB) that's closest

Alternatively, just place this formula in column F:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,IF(D1-INDEX($A:$A,E1)<INDEX($A:$A,E1+1)-D1,E1+1,E1))
```

or use this massive formula in column G:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(D1,$A:$A)+IF(D1-INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(D1,$A:$A))<INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(D1,$A:$A)+1)-D1,1,0))
```

Comment: Thanks! It was actually the wrong reference - it should have been `D1` instead of `A1`, i.e. figure out the delta between the full minute (D1) and the two closest matches. Fixed!

Answer (score 2):

Append minute intervals (in seconds) to ColumnA, ensuring latest time is after existing data, and sort A:B on Time(s) , Smallest to Largest with My data has headers. Filter ColumnB to select only blanks and insert:

> =IF(A4-A3>A5-A4,B5,B3)

into first blank (here Row 4) and copy down, then delete last row:

[image: SU540294 example]

Could relatively easily be extended to interpolate between values (which may be more accurate) rather than simply pick the nearest value.